# How to remove duplicate contacts in vcf file

Tags: android, android-contacts, duplicates, vcf-vcard

Hi guys i have this code which i use to get contacts from the phone and store them in vcf format,the code works properly for contacts that have only one number but i keep getting duplicates for contacts with multiple numbers i.e contacts that have home number,work number e.t.c...any help will be appreciated.....this is my code below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;


    public class Show_contacts extends Activity {
        Cursor cursor;
        ArrayList<String> vCard;
        String vfile;
        static Context mContext;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                mContext = Show_contacts.this;
                getVCF();
            }

            public static void getVCF() {
                final String vfile = "Contacts.vcf";
                Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                phones.moveToFirst();
                for (int i = 0; i < phones.getCount(); i++) {
                    String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
                    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
                    try {
                        fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                        fis.read(buf);
                        String VCard = new String(buf);
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
                        FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
                        mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
                        phones.moveToNext();
                        Log.d("Vcard", VCard);
                        mFileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to check lookupKey. It works for me.

```
Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<String> vCard;
Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> saveLkKey;
String vcfFile;
String currentTime;
String rootStorage;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.save_contact_fragment, container,
            false);

    mContext = getActivity();
    rootStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";

    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();

    currentTime = today.monthDay + "" + (today.month + 1) + "" + today.year
            + "-" + today.format("%k%M%S") + "";

    vcfFile = "myContacts" + currentTime + ".vcf";


    Button btnSaveVcf = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSave1);
    btnSaveVcf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getVCF(vcfFile);

        }

    });

return view;
}

public void getVCF(String vfile) {

    Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    phones.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < phones.getCount(); i++) {
        String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
        lookupKey = lookupKey.trim();

        if (saveLkKey == null) {
            saveLkKey = new ArrayList<String>();
            saveLkKey.add(lookupKey);
        } else {
            if (isDuplicate(lookupKey)) {

                phones.moveToNext();
                continue;
            } else {
                saveLkKey.add(lookupKey);
            }
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
        AssetFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri,
                    "r");
            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String VCard = new String(buf);
            String path = rootStorage + vfile;

            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,
                    true);
            mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
            phones.moveToNext();
            Log.d("Vcard", VCard);
            mFileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public boolean isDuplicate(String lkKey) {
    for (String s : saveLkKey) {
        if (s.equals(lkKey)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: just checked back at this question after 2years, unfortunately i've stopped android development. all the same thanks for answering :)